# Woocommerce single product broken

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm developing a wordpress theme and for some reason, my woocommerce single-product is broken. It displays everything it's suppose too but it looks like css and javascript aren't working.
I already added woocommerce support in my function files.
If I change to twentyfourteen theme, then single-product is working normally.
Can somebody help me out?

Here's the link for the single product page: 
[Link](http://olsnegocios.com.br/clientes/cristinarezendeart/wp/produto/ocean-serie-sob-encomenda/)

Comment: You have jQuery error in common.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WooCommerce classes are not loading on your web page. If you already added WooCommerce theme support, then you might missing WordPress body function.

Make sure you have following line in `functions.php`

```
add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
```

Also include WordPress's body function, `<body>` tag must be like below.

```
<body <?php body_class() ?>>
```

If you already have any class for body, pass that class to this function like

```
<body <?php body_class( 'existing-class' ) ?>>
```

To enable WooCommerce gallery features in your theme you must declare support using add_theme_support() like so;

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'yourtheme_setup' );
function yourtheme_setup() {
    add_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-zoom' );
    add_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-lightbox' );
    add_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-slider' );
}
```

More Info [here](https://woocommerce.wordpress.com/2017/02/28/adding-support-for-woocommerce-2-7s-new-gallery-feature-to-your-theme/)

Comment: Hi @Ahmad Hassan, thank you very much! It was the body_class missing. But I still have problems with changing image, it's not the way it suppose to, can you help me out?

Comment: Looks like it's because of JavaScript, you have 1 error in your custom.js, fix that. Also multiple jQuery scripts are loading on your webpage, the default WordPress jQuery 1.12.4 and another 3.3.1 that you included. Remove 1 either that you included or WordPress's default.

Comment: I added this wp_deregister_script('jquery'); then wp_register_script( 'jquery', $src1, '', '', false); and then wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' ); where $src1 is the path to my jQuery 3.3.1, but 1.12.4 seems to still be loading. Any idea?

Comment: Ok, now there's only one jQuery being loaded but still got the same problem :/

Comment: That did it! Thank you, sir.